# My parents are careless about my marriage

Tags: nikah, parents, curse

I'm a 26 years old girl from a middle class family. My parents are careless about my marriage. They don’t want me to get married fearing that I might not provide for them. They also make an excuse saying we don’t have money. If a guy marries you without anything then we can allow you. Also, they want to live with me forever. I don’t have any problem with that but how can I find such a guy? Isn’t it my parents duty? I was raised in a conservative environment. I can't even talk to guys properly. How can I find a man for me? If I talk about this, my mother calls me in various names that I'm shameless and that's why I want to get married. She also curses me saying I'm not grateful and I will never find happiness and success in life and I'll go to jahannam. They are not fulfilling their duty. Moreover they are cursing me. What can I do? I'm also afraid of her curses as mother's prayers are always answered. I fear that maybe I will never be successful as my mother is cursing me. But I'm a human too and sometimes I get a mental breakdown and I keep shouting. Later on I regret and cry. I also developed  OCD according to a psychiatrist.
N.B: My parents don’t bear my expenses. I earn and contribute to my family.

Comment: you yourself should prepare conditions for marriage while respecting your parents but not obeying them when they say something against Islam. respect with disobey. tell them OK but disobey.